# Typescript confuses classes with the same methods

Tags: typescript, class, interface

I'm creating a system of multiple adapters which requires a map of cases to their adapters.

### Example

```
enum EAnimals {
  cat = 'cat',
  dog = 'dog'
}

interface IAnimal {
  talk(): void
}

class CatAdapter implements IAnimal {
  constructor(name: string) {}

  public talk (): void {
    console.log('meow')
  }
}

class DogAdapter implements IAnimal {
  constructor(name: string) {}

  public talk (): void {
    console.log('woof')
  }
}

type TAnimalToAdapter = {
  [EAnimals.cat]: CatAdapter[],
  [EAnimals.dog]: DogAdapter[],
}

const Adapters: TAnimalToAdapter = {
  [EAnimals.cat]: [
    new CatAdapter('first breed'),
    new CatAdapter('second breed'),
  ],
  [EAnimals.dog]: [
    new DogAdapter('first breed'),
    new CatAdapter('second breed'), // shouldn't happen
  ],
}
```

### Explanation

There is a list of animals and each has its own adapter. `TAnimalToAdapter` is created to differ adapters based on animal they suppose to work with. Both adapters share the same method `talk` which does completely different stuff, but typescript is allowing using both adapters in place of specific one because their methods are named they same.

### What needs to be fixed

I need somehow to tell typescript not to confuse each one with another.

---

Maybe there is a better way to implement this and I definitely would love to hear it.

Comment: TypeScript is _structurally_, not nominally, typed. If the object has the right property, it's acceptable.

Comment: If you add say `dog:never` field to the `DogAdapter` it'll make TS do what you want it to do and will not affect the resulting javascript (it'll be optimized out)